# common lisp: acons in matching lists?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm working through *The Elements of Artificial Intelligence Using Common Lisp* by Steven Tanimoto and I can't figure out his `match` program. So far the idea is to gradually improve upon a self-rolled list `match`, starting with not very good

```
(defun match1 (p s) (equalp p s))
```

Here's `match3`:

```
 (defun match3 (p s)
      (cond
        ((null p) (null s))            ;null clause
        ((or (atom p) (atom s)) nil)   ;atom clause
        ((equalp (first p) (first s))  ;equal CAR clause
         (match3 (rest p) (rest s)))   
        ((eql (first p) '?)            ; joker clause  
         (match3 (rest p) (rest s)))
        (t nil)))                      ;extremal clause
```

the so-called *joker* clause should match, i.e.,

```
(match3 '(a b ? d) '(a b c d))  ; yields t
```

but then the next version should "match" this

```
(match4 '((? x) b c (? y)) '(a b c d))
```

I quote

> This would permit, for example, the (above) form to not only return
>   true, but also return the association of `a` with `x` and the
>   association of `d` with `y`. In that way, if the match is used as a
>   condition in a production rule, the action part of the rule can
>   manipulate the values matching the variable elements in the pattern.

...and then it goes on talking about alist things. Then the rewrite of `match`:

```
(defun4 match4 (p s)
      (cond
        ((and (null p) (null s))
         '((:yes . :yes)))
        ((or (atom p) (atom s)) nil)
        ((equalp (first p) (first s))
         (match4 (rest p) (rest s)))

        ((and
          (equalp (length (first p)) 2)
          (eql (first (first p)) '?)
          (let ((rest-match
                 (match4 (rest p) (rest s))))
            (if rest-match
                (acons (first (rest (first p)))
                       (first s)
                       rest-match)))))
        (t nil)))
```

...so if someone could get me started by first telling me why we want to compare `(? x)` to `a` in the example above, that would help. Basically, I'm not clear on what the goal is here. If someone could explain the motivation behind this, I think I could pick apart the code. Otherwise, I'm totally lost.

Comment: **why we want to compare (? x) to a in the example above, that would help.** do you mean what's the motivation for this kind of pattern matching? It's not that you're comparing them,  it's that you'd return the mapping betweven pattern variables and their values, and that those would be useful later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match3` introduces simple pattern matching between two lists, where the symbol `?` in the first list can match any single symbol in the second list. For this reason the function returns `T` or `NIL`, to denote the success or the failure of the matching process.

Then a new kind of match is introduced in `match4`, through the use of what appear to be a match variable. `(? x)` is simply a way of introducing a match variable, that in other languages could be written as `?x`, or something similar. The idea is that this variable “captures” the symbol matched on the second list, so that, for instance, you could later use it in a way similar to this:

```
(match '(a (? x) (? y) (? x) b) '(a c d c b)) ; yes, since ‘c’ matches ‘?x’
(match '(a (? x) (? y) (? x) b) '(a c d e b)) ; no, since ‘c’ and ‘e’ are different
```

For this to be used effectively, the function `match` must give, when a match is found, not simply the value `T`, but the couple `(match variable, symbol matched)`, and build with it an associative list of matches found. So, `match4` returns such list through the use of `acons`, in the last branch of the cond (first it gets `rest-match`, than “aconses” over it the pair given by the match variable and the symbol found). The special pair `(:yes . :yes)` is simply a way of terminating this list of matches.

I suppose that later in the book will be presented another version of the match function in which the matches found will be used in the subsequent part of the process.

Comment: I plug in your `(match '(a (? x) (? y) (? x) b) '(a c d c b))` and get `((X . C) (Y . D) (X . C) (:YES . :YES))` But what is this? What is the point? What does it have to do with comparing two lists for "similarity?" Sorry I'm so dense here.

Comment: @147pm You use this all the time, whether you realize it or not.  Every function in Lisp accepts a list of arguments.  Rather than making you write `(defun foo list-of-arguments (let ((x (first list-of-arguments)) (y (second list-of-arguments)) ...)` and destructure the argument list yourself, Common Lisp lets you write `(defun foo (x y) ...)` and have function calls checked for the right number of arguments, and to bind the first element of the argument list to x, and the second to y.  It's just pattern matching really.  It's a useful tool.  Keep reading;  I expect the book uses it, too.

Comment: In function `match4` you obtain that result, but later on (with some advanced match) you will obtain something like `((X . C) (Y . D) (:YES . :YES))`, that is the assignement to the variabiles that make possibile the match. In other words, `X` and `Y` are variables: only if they have the *same* value during the match, that match is satisfied. In my second example, now `match4` returns `((X . C) (Y . D) (X . E) (:YES . :YES))`, but on a  more advanced version `match_n` will give `NIL`, that is a match error, since you have two different values for `X`, `C` and `E`, and this is impossible.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor, et al: Thank you both for your "Lisp Lore/Wisdom." I see alist used a lot in Lisp and need to grok the lore of it. I sense there's a lot for a beginner to learn in Tanimoto's book, but teasing it out will be difficult. Let me know if you have any other book (etc) suggestions for "deep Lisp lore/wisdom".

Answer (score 0):

I have tanimoto's book, but won't have access to it until tomorrow at the earliest,  but the example mentioned in the quote is actually a good one:

> in that way, if the match is used as a condition in a production rule, the action part of the rule can manipulate the values matching the variable elements in the pattern.

[Production rule systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_system_(computer_science)) are a good example of where this kind of matching is useful. It lets rule writers focus on domain knowledge, and to keep algorithms for processing rules separate.

Some approaches to functional programming also make heavy use of pattern matching.  Programing language support varies,  though.  Common Lisp makers it easy to wrote your own though.

Comment: Could you give an example of this "...can manipulate the values matching the variable elements in the pattern?"

Comment: @147pm I don't think anything particular special is meant by it.  For the moment, just treat it as shorthand for `(let* ((value '(a b c d)) (x (first value)) (y (third value))) ...here you can use x and y...)`.  I think by "manipulate" is just meant that you have access to those values now.